# Let $K$ be a normal sugroup of $G$, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Show that $K\cap H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have a problem that saying

> Suppose $K$ is a subgroup normal of $G$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
> Show that $K \cap H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

I've tried to show it by first showing that $K \cap H$ is not the empty set, because identity element is in $K \cap H$. Then, I show that $K \cap H$ is a subgroup. After that, I use the normal subgroup test:

> Take arbitrary element $a \in K \cap H$, this means that b is element of K and element of H.
>
> $aha^{-1} = h1hh2 = h$ is element of $H$, for all a element of $K \cap H$, and $h$ element of $H$

So, $K \cap H$ is normal subgroup of $H$.
However, I'm not really sure about this, and I wondering what is the use of the information saying that $K$ is normal subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently we know that $K \cap H$ is a subgroup of $H$ given that the intersection of subgroups is a subgroup and $K \cap H \subset H$. As you ascertained then, the only thing left to establish is that $K \cap H$ is normal in $H$.

Normalcy boils down to the condition that the each left coset of $K \cap H$ is equivalent to the right coset generated by the same element (that is, $h(K \cap H) = (K \cap H)h$, where $h \in H$). We can easily establish this is equivalent to the following condition:

$$\forall h \in H, \forall a \in H \cap K, hah^{-1} \in H \cap K $$

Note then what normalcy looks like for $K \subset G$; we have:

$$\forall g \in G, \forall k \in K, gkg^{-1} \in K$$

Let then for this sake $h \in H$ and $a \in H \cap K$. As $H \subset G$ and $H \cap K \subset K$, we notice $hah^{-1} \in K$ by the previous condition. Moreover, $h, a,$ and $h^{-1}$ are in $H$ by assumption, so $hah^{-1} \in H$. Combining these yields $hah^{-1} \in H \cap K$, and so $H \cap K$ is normal in $H$.

I think your confusion may stem from an error in your definition of normalcy. If we want for example $K$ normal in $G$, we want to show the conjugation of any element of $K$ by an element in $G$ (i.e. $gkg^{-1}$) is an element of $K$, not just an element of $G$ (as this follows by closure).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I still have a confusion over the intersection of a subgroup is a subgroup, there you said that K intersect H is a subgroup of H, but can we also say that K intersect H is a subgroup of K?

Comment: Yes. Recall the definition of what a subgroup is; it is the subset of a group that forms a group still under the same binary operation.

Comment: There is more than one definition of a subgroup; granted, they're equivalent, but there is no "*the*" definition.